# WPF UserControl Style

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles

I want to set the background property of all the usercontrols of my project.

I tried with

```
<style TargetType={x:Type UserControl}>
    <setter property="Background" Value="Red" />
</style>
```

It compiles but didn't work.

¿Any Idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

You can only set a a style to a specific class, so this will work (create a UserControl object, not very useful):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <UserControl Name="control" Content="content"></UserControl>
</Grid>
```

But this doesn't (Create a class derived from UserControl):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <l:MyUserControl Name="control" Content="content"></l:MyUserControl>
</Grid>
```

What you can do is either explicitly set the style using the Style property:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" x:Key="UCStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <l:MyUserControl Name="control" Content="content" Style="{StaticResource UCStyle}"></l:MyUserControl>
</Grid>
```

or create a style for each derived class, you can use BasedOn to avoid duplicating the style content:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" x:Key="UCStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type l:MyUserControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource UCStyle}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <l:MyUserControl Name="control" Content="content"></l:MyUserControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: These are the two options that exist for styling in WPF.

Comment: @Fëanor - x:Type is sometimes optional

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing some double quotes:

Try this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <UserControl Name="control" Content="content"></UserControl>
</Grid>
```