# Disabling UserControls in a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I've got an application consisting of a `TabControl` with `TabItem`s that are hosting custom `UserControl`s like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="UC_1 and UC_2">
        <StackPanel>
            <local:UC_1/>
            <Separator/>
            <local:UC_2/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="UC_3">
        <local:UC_3/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="UC_4">
        <local:UC_3/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The `UserControl`s have a bunch of different controls on them, like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Surname"/>
            <Border>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Surname}" />
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Firstname" />
            <Border>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Firstname}" />
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now I want to set the whole `TabControl` to `ReadOnly`, depending on a property in the Model, so the user can still read but not edit the content of the controls.
Unfortunately, `IsReadOnly` is not a property of a `TabControl`, nor a `TabItem` nor a `UserControl`. So I decided to go with the `IsEnabled`-property instead.

But if I disable the whole `TabControl`, the user would be unable to switch between the `TabItems` anymore to read the data, as those cannot be clicked on if they are disabled (which seems legit, given the meaning of the `IsEnabled`-property).

So, to achieve my "diabled but still clickable"-`TabItem`s, I've tried to setup a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` inside the Resources of the `TabControl`, so disable the `UserControl`s inside the `TabItem`s instead of the whole `TabControl` or the `TabItem`s:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.TCEnabledProperty}" Value="9">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

But this is not working.

So I changed

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
```

to

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
```

and suddenly I got the expected behavior **but** (of course) **only** if the given `UserControl` has a `StackPanel` hosting all the other controls, what is not the case for all of those `UserControl`s.

### The main question here is now:

Why is the `Style` working for the `TargetType = StackPanel` but not for the `TargetType = UserControl`? I don't get the point that I can access the Controls *inside* the `UserControl` but not the `UserControl` itself.

If there is no other option, I'll just add a wrapping `StackPanel` to the `UserControl`s not having one already, but for the sake of curiosity I would like to understand the whole behavior I'm experiencing here...

Comment: Simply add `IsReadOnly` dependency property to `UserControl`.

Comment: Have you considered to set IsEnabled="False" on tabitems' content only? The stackpanel in first tab, usercontrol in second and third tab.

Comment: `<Style TargetType="UserControl"?` does not work, because implicit styles works only with concrete types and not base classes. Concrete type is UC_1 in this case and UserControl is jast a base class. You may try to create explicit style (with Key) and explicitelly set the style on all usercontrols in tab items

Comment: @Liero Applying `<UserControl IsEnabled="False"/>` to the `UserControl`s was exactly what I came up with in the first place, but did not work as I described in my question. ;-) I just found out why this is the case, see my own anser below to see why that is the case and what I finally ended up with.

Comment: In your question I dont see where you tried to set IsEnabled="false". You tried to create style, but the style was never applied, but that's different problem.

Comment: @Liero This is not the actual code, for the sake of simplicity. I tried to apply the Style between `<TabControl>` and `<TabItem Header="UC_1 and UC_2">` in my first code block (inside of the `<TabControl.Resources>` declaration).

Comment: I have written an answer for better demonstration of what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont just bind each TabItem's content IsEnabled property separatelly?

```
<TabItem Header="UC_1 and UC_2">
    <StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding ...}"/> <!-- use converter if you can't create property called 'IsTCEnabled' in viewmodel -->
        <local:UC_1 />
        <Separator />
        <local:UC_2 />
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="UC_3">
    <local:UC_3 IsEnabled="{Binding ...}"/>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="UC_4">
    <local:UC_3 IsEnabled="{Binding ...}"/>
</TabItem>
```

you may also create style to avoid repeating the binding:

```
<Style x:Key="TabContent" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
   <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding }" />
</Style>

<TabItem Header="UC_1 and UC_2">
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource TabContent}" />                      
        <local:UC_1 />
        <Separator />
        <local:UC_2 />
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="UC_3">
    <local:UC_3 Style="{StaticResource TabContent}" />
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="UC_4">
    <local:UC_3 Style="{StaticResource TabContent}" />
</TabItem>
```

**EDIT:** Answer to your question

> Why is the Style working for the TargetType = StackPanel but not for
>   the TargetType = UserControl?

it's simple. StackPanel style works, because you have added StackPanel to the first tab. UserControl does not work, because you have added UC_1 and UC_2 to the second tab. Implicit styles does not work for inherited controls. TargetType must exactly match the type of the element.

Comment: Nice point! I like the second version even more, because it implements references to a StaticResource (instead of applying shotgun surgery to the whole xaml), which results in reasonable maintainability. Thank you for your effort! :-)

Comment: Another solution just came to my mind: You could edit template of the TabControl and set the binding to IsEnabled property of the ContentPresenter where content of selected tab is presented :)

Comment: Actually, the `StackPanels` in my `UserControl`s became disabled too, as the style of the View punched through into the `UserControl` that have concrete `StackPanels` objects as well (see my own answer for reference).

Comment: I know, it is expected behaviour. Implicit styles are valid in all element in given context. In this case, context is visual subtree of the TabControl

Comment: Yes, and I was trying to abuse this behavior to disable the controls inside my `UserControl`s. But I like your approach much more, as it is actually selective and not so "hacky" like mine. Disableing of the UCs is a job of the actual View, the UCs base classes do not need to (and cannot) know if they should be editable in the given context of the program.

Comment: In general, if you need to apply the same logic for all items in ItemsControl (TabControl is derived from ItemsControl), you should consider ItemsSource property. You could then easily apply the logic in ItemTemplate or ItemContainerStyle and you don't have to repeat it forech tab. Remember, ItemsControls are here to avoid violation of DRY principle in xaml

Comment: DRY is always one of my personal top goals. Do you have a link at hand that could provide me (and later readers) with some more information about the implementation of `ItemTemplate` and/or `ItemContainerStyle`, so we don't blow up the comments with to much conversation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85295/discussion-between-liero-and-m463).

Answer (score 0):

Add `IsReadOnly` dependency property to `UserControl`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Surname"/>
            <Border>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Surname}" />
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Firstname" />
            <Border>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Model.Firstname}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Model.Firstname}"     />
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and code (could be done using bindings and converters, `x:Name`-way is just quicker way to demonstrate):

```
public bool IsReadOnly
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsReadOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, (d, e) =>
    {
        var userControl = (MyUserControl)s;
        var value = (bool)e.NewValue;
        userControl.textBlock.Visible = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        userControl.textBox.Visible = !value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }));
```

Then you should be able to set it in tab page:

```
<TabItem Header="MyUserControl">
    <local:MyUserControl IsReadOnly="{Binding SomeBinding}"/>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this doesn't answer the main question: *why isn't the setter working for `TargetType=UserControl`*. In addition, I've got like 60+ `UserControl`s that I am building my Views out of, and this would involve a major change (and even a modification to the code behind) to all of them, instead of just throwing in a handful of `StackPanel`s into the ones not already having one hosting their controls...

Comment: @M463, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/632356/1997232) question to make it working with style. Regarding `60+`, disabling whole `UserControl` is a *workaround*, my answer is a *more* proper solution.

Comment: If you've got 60+ usercontrols and you are adding them to the TabControl one by one like shown on the picture, you should consider refactorig the presentation layer architecture. We may chat about it if you're interested.

Comment: Nope, I've got a *repository* of 60+ `UserControl`s that I use to compose different Views as needed. Each of those Views consists of not more than 10 of those UCs, but each View needs a different composition. This is for a business application with different forms inside a window, in which each form is presented by a special `UserControl` containing all the `TextBoxe`s, `ComboBoxe`s, `CheckBoxe`s etc. needed to take in the data entered by the users.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit:**
>   [Liero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475727/liero) provided an even better solution to the problem. I'm still leaving my answer up, as I was confusing base classes with concrete objects by the time I was wondering why I was unable to apply a `Style` to `TargetType=UserControl` in my View and the text below might help others to understand the difference as well.

The discussion in the comments to [Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr)s answer lead me to another post here on stackoverflow, where I found [the solution to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/634006/3336376).

**Why isn't the setter working for `TargetType=UserControl`?**

The short answer is:

`Style`s can only be applied to *concrete objects*.

`UserControl` is just a class, *not a concrete object*. The concrete object would be `<local:UC_1/>`.

The `StackPanels` on the other hand, surely *are* concrete objects, even though they are hosted further down the visual tree, inside the `UserControl`, and therefore a `Style` can be applied.

Also, it seems like `Style`s can only be set from top down if there is not already a `Style` set for the object in the `UserControl`.
Any `Style` I'm trying to set from top down would just be overridden again by the `Style` nested deeper inside the visual tree (last `Style` wins).
This applies to any `Style`s set by a `ResourceDirectory` for objects in a `UserControl` as well.